# Задача с матрицами

Tags: c, матрицы

Здравствуйте помогите найти ошибку, ввожу оценки студентов и в результате все считается в неявках.
Вот код:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "locale.h"

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n, i, j, k1 = 0, k2 = 0, k3 = 0, k4 = 0, k5 = 0;
    printf("Введите количество студентов");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    int **A = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        A[i] = (int *)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    }
    printf("Ввод оценок\n");
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Студент: ", i);
        for (j = 1; j < 3; j++)
            scanf_s("%d", &A[i,j]);
    }
    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
        for (j = 1; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (A[i, j] = 1)
                k1++;
            else if (A[i, j] = 2) 
                k2++;
            else if (A[i, j] = 3) 
                k3++;
            else if (A[i, j] = 4) 
                k4++;
            else k5++;
        }
    printf("Неявки=%d\n", k1);
    printf("Неудовлетворительные оценки=%d\n", k2);
    printf("Удовлетворительные оценки=%d\n", k3);
    printf("Хорошие оценки=%d\n", k4);
    printf("Отличные оценки=%d\n", k5);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        free(A[i]);
    }
    free(A);
}
```

Comment: `if (A[i, j] == 1)`

Comment: @Igor, вернее, `if (A[i][j] == 1)`? :-)

Comment: @Vladimir, а подскажите пожалуйста еще, почему я ввожу, например, кол-во студентов 3, а вводится у меня только для двоих?

Comment: А это потому, что у Вас ввод идет от 1, а массивы индексируются с 0.